# java stack overflow due to recursive constructor calling

Tags: java

I am new to java programmming. Today this example is tought by my teacher in non static method. Any body tell me detailed answer from the point of jvm architecture

```
class Example {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    Example e1 = new Example();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("main method start");
        Example e2 = new Example();
        System.out.println("main method end");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class Example {

    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;

    Example e1 = new Example(); // this is the reason
```

What is happening is when you call new Example in your main() method, 
`Example e1=new Example();` is being executed.

In `Example e1=new Example();` you are again creating a new object of `Example()` which will again call `new Example()` (recursive calls to new `Example()` leads to `StackOverflowError`).